# Installing Dri-core floor panel after framing. Do the panels still need the 1/4in spacing?

Tags: basement, flooring, framing

I assume the spacing is to keep the lumber off of the cement walls. I used rigid foam panels on all exterior walls already. Any reason not to butt the panels all the way up to the framing?

Also.
People recommend not putting dricore down first and framing on top in case there is a water issue. If that is a concern then wouldn't it make sense to install floor panels before drywall? Either way the dricore would be damaged but the drywall might be ok depend on the water depth.

Comment: Don't quite understand your question. A gap is usually left between the floor panel and the wall to accommodate the expansion of the wood. So, in normal construction, the floor would be installed after the erection of the wall, and the gap sealed by the kick-board and edge trim

Comment: Thanks. Didn't consider expansion.